# Magento 2 how to login user in specific store programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, login

How can I login customer in specific store programmatically in Magento 2?
I've tried to override **execute** method of

> Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost

and did something like this:

```
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore("store_code");
$store = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode("store_code");
$this->httpContext->setValue("store", "store_code", "default");
$this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);

$customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

But it didn't work.
I need to do main store, where customer will insert his credentials, and after that customer will logged in and redirected to store according to his customer group

Comment: why you don't use account share at  option?